# I am trying to create a roll No. list of students in class by calling a javascript function and then putting the latest entry into an array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function, for-loop

Hi I want to be able to input on screen the name and roll no. of a new student and add that student to the existing list of students using Javascript function and for loop and array and display the fresh list on the same page.

I am able to get the page to input the new student and roll no. and also display the confirmation.
But when I click"Submit" the console shows Violation: [Violation] 'click' handler took 4061ms.

Please have a look and let me know where I am going wrong.

Here is my code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Javascript Arrays</title>
  <script type="text/Javascript">

var array = [];
function addtolist(){
    var x = document.getElementById("fname").value;
    array[x] = document.getElementById("rNo").value;
    alert ("Ok, " + x + " added in the class list with roll no. " + array [x]);

    for (var i = 0; i<array.length; i++){
        document.write("</br>"+ x + ":" + array [x]);
    }
}

  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 id= "title">Roll No. Entry</h1>
  <p1> Enter Roll No. and First Name and Click Submit </p1><br><br>
  <label for="fname"> First Name: </label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"/><br>
  <label for="rNo"> Roll No: </label><br>
  <input type="number" id="rNo" name="rNo"/><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="addtolist()">
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```js
const allStudents = [];

const addtolist = () => {
  const fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  const rNo = document.getElementById("rNo").value;
  document.getElementById("fname").value = "";
  document.getElementById("rNo").value = "";

  const newStudent = {
    fname,
    rNo
  }

  allStudents.push(newStudent);

  renderList();
}

const renderList = () => {
  const studentCount = allStudents.length;
  const lastAdded = allStudents[studentCount - 1];

  const newListItem = document.createElement("div");
  newListItem.textContent = `Name: ${lastAdded.fname} Roll Number: ${lastAdded.rNo}`

  document.body.append(newListItem);
}
```

```html
<h1 id="title">Roll No. Entry</h1>
<p1> Enter Roll No. and First Name and Click Submit </p1><br><br>
<label for="fname"> First Name: </label><br>
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" /><br>
<label for="rNo"> Roll No: </label><br>
<input type="number" id="rNo" name="rNo" /><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="addtolist()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey thats not how array works in javascript. Arrays do not have custom keys in javascript like php associative array. So you can try appending objects in the array.
Here's a working code of what you're trying to achieve:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Javascript Arrays</title>
  <script type="text/Javascript">

var array = [];
function addtolist(){
    var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
    var roll = document.getElementById("rNo").value;
    array.push({
      fname: fname,
      roll: roll
    });
    alert ("Ok, " + fname + " added in the class list with roll no. " + roll);

    for (var i = 0; i<array.length; i++){
      console.log(i, 'kk')
        document.write("</br>"+ fname + ":" + roll);
    }
}

  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 id= "title">Roll No. Entry</h1>
  <p1> Enter Roll No. and First Name and Click Submit </p1><br><br>
  <label for="fname"> First Name: </label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"/><br>
  <label for="rNo"> Roll No: </label><br>
  <input type="number" id="rNo" name="rNo"/><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="addtolist()">
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped.
I also want to be able to print the array on the same page and not the next page.